# Try/Except not catching a "greater than" error

Tags: python, django, try-except

The following code does not work :

```
try:
    get_current_player(request).cash >= bid # does the player have enough cash for this bid ?
except ValueError:
    messages.error(request, "You don't have the necessary funds to place a bid of <span class='cash'>%d</span> !" % (bid))
messages.success(request, "You placed a bid of %d !" % (bid))
```

When the bid is higher than the current player's cash, the success message is printed instead of the error message.

However, the following code works, indicating the values are correct :

```
if get_current_player(request).cash >= bid : # does the player have enough cash for this bid ?
    messages.success(request, "You placed a bid of %d !" % (bid))
else :
    messages.error(request, "You don't have the necessary funds to place a bid of <span class='cash'>%d</span> !" % (bid))
```

Am I using try/except wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are using try/except wrong. Comparison does not throw any exceptions, because it is not exceptional if the outcome is False. Your second code is the correct way to handle such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `try`/`except` if you expect the comparison `get_current_player(request).cash >= bid` to always work and not produce an error. Use `if`/`else` as in your second block of code.

With your first block of code, `get_current_player(request).cash >= bid` is tried and evaluated to `True`/`False`. As long as this comparison doesn't produce a `ValueError` (and there's no obvious reason why it should), the `except` block doesn't execute.

The `except` block will not run just because the comparison evaluated as `False`.

**Edit**: If you think there is a possibility that evaluating `get_current_player(request).cash >= bid` will raise an exception, you could put the `if`/`else` block inside the `try` block:

```
try:
    if get_current_player(request).cash >= bid:
        messages.success(request, "You placed a bid of %d !" % (bid))
    else:
        messages.error(request, "You don't have the necessary funds to place a bid of <span class='cash'>%d</span> !" % (bid))

except ValueError:
    # handle the ValueError
```

You may want to allow for any other errors the comparison could trigger too (e.g. `AttributeError`).

Comment: I see, thank you. Usually, the cash should be enough. It is a rare occurence for it not to be. Thus, it seemed to me like try/except was the best way to go, because it avoids nesting when I just want to check that the player has enough cash. Is there a way to use try/except for this purpose, or is it not good practice to do so ?

Comment: @Brachamul You can certainly use both together - I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Why this

```
get_current_player(request).cash >= bid
```

should return Error? Is this wrong? No. Thats why u dont have ValueError on this.